# Can 'unless' value be incremented?

Tags: ruby

I'm testing the reserved word `unless` with the following code, which increments the value of `x`.

```
x = 1
unless x >= 2
  puts "x is less than 2"
else
  puts "x is greater than 2"
  x = x + 1
end
```

The output is:

```
x is less than 2
```

Does `unless` support the increment of `x`?

Comment: `x = x+1` is only invoked in `else` part of your logic, so it's not incremented because it gets it unless clause (and skips the else block). What control flow are you looking for?

Comment: I think you are getting confused between `loops` and `conditional statements`

Comment: Are you looking for [`until`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-until+Loop)?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear. But it is clear that the only place in your code that increments a variable:

```
x = x + 1
```

is not executed because the condition `unless x >= 2` is always met.